# unregister_setting() vs delete_option() for plugin update

Tags: plugin-development, functions

I have a plugin (my first major one) and I have some registered settings that are no longer needed.  I would like to have these old settings removed from the database to tidy things up and not confuse users with the new settings that will be in the options table.

I set them like this:

```
register_setting('general_section', 'nav_option_one');
register_setting('general_section', 'nav_option_two');
```

When I tried to remove them with `unregister_setting()` nothing seemed to happen (at least on the DB):

```
unregister_setting('general_section', 'nav_option_one');
unregister_setting('general_section', 'nav_option_two');
```

I then when about it with `delete_option()` and it removed the row from the DB as expected.  However, I am concerned I am missing something.

Can you please let me know what the best method of removing old options settings from the database and what's supposed to happen when using `unregister_setting()` is used?  I tried looking it up, but no help there: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_setting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`register_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_setting/) / [`unregister_setting()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/unregister_setting/) are used to let WordPress know that it should allow / remove a given setting name—to set up the "allowed options" list, etc. You're telling WordPress that the setting `my_name` will exist, and that it is allowed to be used by the [Settings API](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/settings-api/).

[`add_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_option/) / [`delete_option()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/delete_option/) actually do the work of adding / removing the value of the `my_name` setting (or option) from the database.

If you've changed the way your plugin sets up its data, you might need to use `delete_option()` to remove the data that's already been stored. However, if you're registering different settings, you shouldn't need to use `unregister_setting()` on the old ones, since the allowed settings list isn't stored in the database.